# Sorting the columns of a JavaFX TableView

Tags: tableview, javafx-8

Now I have been searching for quite a while and all I find are people trying to sort the TableRows through a TableColumn, but I want to sort the TableColumns alphabetically.

Say I have a Table with the columns 'Name', 'Pain' and 'Gain' and after sorting I would like it to be 'Gain', 'Name' and 'Pain'.

Can't really figure out a way to do this, but it can't be that hard, can it ?

... I wanna do it programmatically of course and not drag the columns around.

Comment: Why not make a `Comparator<TableColumn>` that sorts by column name and then just `myTableView.getColumns().sort(myComparator)`?

Comment: Well, indeed why not ? Thanks, I knew it couldn't be that hard.

Comment: To me this seems unnecessary in most use cases though. Why not simply add the columns in the correct order instead of applying an algorithm that will yield a result that is easy to determine...

Comment: Funny ) . I'll add an answer.  Hopefully you can accept it so this question gets marked as answered.

Comment: @fabian well then I guess my use case is uncommon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I don't have time to post code right now, but here is a method that should work:

- Create a `Comparator<TableColumn>` that will sort by column name.
- Apply the sort by `myTableView.getColumns().sort(myComparator)`

Where `myTableView` is the name of your `TableView` and `myComparator` is the name of the `Comparator<TableColumn>` you created.

Comment: no worries, I was just to dumb to come up with that way myself, I know how to write a Comparator though :)